# Passing input from a textfile into a function

Tags: import

I have a text file which is a list of numbers and would like to pass each number in the list as input to a Mathematica function.

For example, my text might contain [2, 1, 4], and I would like to pass this into `CompleteGraph`, so that it returns, `CompleteGraph[2]`,  `CompleteGraph[1]`, `CompleteGraph[4]`.

How might I do this? I come from python and think a for loop would work but I don't have any idea about how to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: Import["file.txt"]

Comment: If your text contains "[..]" as list separators, you must them first change to braces by: "StringReplace[string,{"["->"{", "]"->"}"}] " and then you can evaluate the string ny: "Evaluate[string]". Having created this list of data, you can feed it to "CompleteGraph["